# Following "getting started" diesel tutorial, but with sqlite, causes

Tags: sqlite, rust, rust-diesel

I'm trying to follow: https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started but I'm using:

```
echo DATABASE_URL=/tmp/diesel_demo.sqlite > .env
```

instead of a Postgres database.

I've changed all occurrences of `Pg` to `Sqlite`, and `SERIAL` to `INT`, but get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `i32: FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, Sqlite>` is not satisfied
  --> src/bin/show_posts.rs:14:10
   |
14 |         .load::<Post>(&connection)
   |          ^^^^ the trait `FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, Sqlite>` is not implemented for `i32`    
How to get a result set where field value == row number?
```

show_posts.rs:

```
extern crate diesel_demo;
extern crate diesel;

use self::diesel_demo::*;
use self::models::*;
use self::diesel::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    use diesel_demo::schema::posts::dsl::*;

    let connection = establish_connection();
    let results = posts.filter(published.eq(true))
        .limit(5)
        .load::<Post>(&connection)
        .expect("Error loading posts");

    println!("Displaying {} posts", results.len());
    for post in results {
        println!("{}", post.title);
        println!("----------\n");
        println!("{}", post.body);
    }
}
```

up.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  body TEXT NOT NULL,
  published BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 'f'
)
```

models.rs (autogenerated):

```
#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct Post {
    pub id: i32,
    pub title: String,
    pub body: String,
    pub published: bool,
}
```

I don't understand why Diesel expects `id` to be `Nullable`.

Comment: Diesel expects `id` to be `Nullable<Integer>` because sqlite does indicate via `PRAGMA TABLE_INFO('…')` that this column can be nullable. You can see the inferred types in your `schema.rs` file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding `NOT NULL` to the `id` field in `up.sql` fixed it.